# Wikipedia url stopped after 10 redirects error GoLang

Tags: redirect, go, https

Upon executing an HTTP Get request, I receive the following error:

```
2015/08/30 16:42:09 Get https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies: 
stopped after 10 redirects
```

In the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    response, err := http.Get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

I know that according to the documentation,

```
// Get issues a GET to the specified URL. If the response is one of
// the following redirect codes, Get follows the redirect, up to a
// maximum of 10 redirects:
//
//    301 (Moved Permanently)
//    302 (Found)
//    303 (See Other)
//    307 (Temporary Redirect)
//
// An error is returned if there were too many redirects or if there
// was an HTTP protocol error. A non-2xx response doesn't cause an
// error.
```

I was hoping that somebody knows what the solution would be in this case. It seems rather odd that this simple url results in more than ten redirects. Makes me think that there may be more going on behind the scenes.

Thank you.

Comment: if you just want to fix this problem, i suggest to change the http package source.

Comment: I have a feeling something else is amiss here.  Not only does that request work from telnet / curl without a single redirect, but your example program (once I do something with response) works as well without any redirects.  Are you going through some sort of proxy perhaps and that is what is causing the redirects?

Comment: Does it work using curl?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you should first give thought to why you are encountering so many HTTP redirects.   Go's default policy of stopping at 10 redirects is reasonable.   More than 10 redirects could mean you are in a redirect loop.   That could be caused outside your code.  It could be induced by something about your network configuration, proxy servers between you and the website, etc.

That said, if you really do need to change the default policy, you do not need to resort to editing the net/http source as someone suggested.

To change the default handling of redirects you will need to create a Client and set CheckRedirect.

For your reference:
http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client

```
// If CheckRedirect is nil, the Client uses its default policy,
// which is to stop after 10 consecutive requests.
CheckRedirect func(req *Request, via []*Request) error
```

Comment: He is getting a redirect-loop. Checking the redirects isn't going to prevent whatever is causing the server to send them.

Comment: Good point.   I had not thought about why he was running up against the default policy of 10 redirects.    I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Wikipedia URLs containing `%26` because they redirect to a version of the URL with `&` which Go then encodes to `%26` which Wikipedia redirects to `&` and ...

Oddly, removing `gcc-go` (v1.4) from my Arch box and replacing it with `go` (v1.5) has fixed the problem.

I'm guessing this can be put down to the changes in `net/http` between v1.4 and v1.5 then.