# Spring Boot controller gets redirected request from Golang app twice

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, go, redirect

Encountered a strange issue,

I'm trying to send redirect from my Golang app to Spring Boot controller, and back from Spring Boot controller to Golang app's endpoint.

Here's my Golang code for redirection:

```
u.counter++ // initially 0, incremented prior to each redirect

u.logger.Printf("sending redirect number: "+strconv.Itoa(u.counter))

http.Redirect(w, r, "http://myspringboot.app/api/mycontroller?param=" + param + "&counter=" + strconv.Itoa(u.counter), 302)
```

and this is Spring Boot controller serving `/api/mycontroller` endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("/mycontroller")
public void getRedirect(
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
        @RequestParam("param") String param,
        @RequestParam("counter") String counter
) {
    System.out.println("param: " + param + " counter: " + counter);
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", "https://mygolang.app/endpoint?param=" + param);
    httpServletResponse.setStatus(302);
}
```

I send 5 redirects from Golang app, hence I see exactly 5 logs as below, on Golang side:

```
sending redirect number: 1
sending redirect number: 2
sending redirect number: 3
sending redirect number: 4
sending redirect number: 5
```

and on Spring Boot side, I see 10 logs as below:

```
param: somevalue counter: 1
param: somevalue counter: 2
param: somevalue counter: 1
param: somevalue counter: 2
param: somevalue counter: 3
param: somevalue counter: 3
param: somevalue counter: 4
param: somevalue counter: 4
param: somevalue counter: 5
param: somevalue counter: 5
```

And interestingly, if I remove these two lines from Spring Boot controller:

```
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", "https://mygolang.app/endpoint?param=" + param);
httpServletResponse.setStatus(302);
```

then controller receives exactly 5 redirect requests as expected (not 10).
Anyone has seen this issue before?

`/endpoint` on Golang app is completely different from http handler in which I'm doing redirection to Spring Boot.

Both apps run on AWS ECS with one task allocated for each app.
Golang app is on `https` and Spring Boot is on `http`. Going to add ACM certificate for Spring Boot app to check if that's the reason. Any other ideas are appreciated.
UPD. Added ACM certificate to Spring Boot, the issue is still there
UPD2. So far was testing on Chrome. On Microsoft Edge it repeats sometimes 2 and sometimes 3 times

Answer (score 0):

Looks like **/endpoint** at GO side is redirecting back to spring app. Because as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32303438/175554) Go http client has 10 redirect limit.

So basically you are redirecting in between GO<->SB and after 10 GO is stopping.

```java
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", "https://mygolang.app/endpoint?param=" + param);
httpServletResponse.setStatus(302);
```

[Those 2 lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8756734/175554) means redirect the request to GO with 302 status. When you delete this side you are not redirecting back to "GO" so you break  the loop.

Comment: but `/endpoint` does not do any redirection, it returns HTTP 200 with `image/gif` in response

Comment: and even if it would be doing redirection, that would produce 10 duplicates, not just 2 or 3

Comment: (by the way, when i open "developer tools" in Chrome, click "Network" and initiate the requests, it shows exactly 5 redirects from go to spring, and exactly 5 redirects from spring back to go, as expected. there are no duplicate requests)

Comment: if you share a reproducer for SB and go we can test too.